# Obtaining feature extent while iterating using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, extents, loop, iteration

I have a polygon layer upon which i want to create a point layer (regular points) depending on each feature's extent of the polygon layer. So far i have to create a field containing the adequate string:
`concat(x_min($geometry),',', x_max($geometry),',', y_min($geometry),',', y_max($geometry)`

And then parse that field in a loop:

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feature.attributes()
processing.runalg("qgis:regularpoints",attrs[14],1000,0,False,True,outfile)
```

Since my approach appears to be rather bulky and inflexible i was wondering whether there are more direct ways to get the extends - something like `layer.getFeaturesExt()` or `layer.getFeaturesBbox()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `layer` is your polygon layer, you may use this code:

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    bbox = feature.geometry().boundingBox()
    bbox_extent = '%f,%f,%f,%f' % (bbox.xMinimum(), bbox.xMaximum(), bbox.yMinimum(), bbox.yMaximum())
    processing.runalg("qgis:regularpoints",bbox_extent,1000,0,False,True,outfile)
```

and you will create a grid of regular points for each feature of your polygon layer (without the needing of preliminarily creating a field that stores the coordinates).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, it works! but still i am wondering why there isn't a less verbose way since a lot of these vector creation tools require the extend in that specific string formatting...

Comment: @maxwhere I'm glad it worked! However, you have done the job with four lines of code, I don't think it is too much verbose :)